# Access denied for user 'grondon'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Tags: php, html, mysql

I've tried many ways, and search and read a lot through stack overflow, but I can't solve this problem. 
I'm trying to INSERT a form (user's email) into my table of a databank in Mysql.
I've other pages and it works, but specifically for this one, it does not work at all.

This is my HTML code with the form:

```
 <div class="col-sm-4">

   <form action="//domain.com/subscribe.php" method="post" id="postcontent"> 

     <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Tape your e-mail..." required />
     <button type="submit" class="btn-danger btn-subscribe-danger"  >Subscribe!</button>

   </form>
 </div>
```

Now this is the subscribe.php, that receives the POST.

```
<?php
// Inclui o arquivo que faz a conexÃ£o ao MySQL
include("http://domain.com/conection.php");

if($_POST) {

//incluindo as variáveis do formulário postado
$email_post = ($_POST['email']);

// Manipulamos as variÃ¡veis para evitar problemas com aspas e outros caracteres protegidos do MySQL
$email = mysql_escape_string($email_post);

// Montamos a consulta SQL
$query = "INSERT INTO 'mailinglist' ('id','email') VALUES (NULL, '".$email."')";

// Executa a query
$inserir = mysql_query($query);

if ($inserir) {

// Enter the email where you want to receive notification
$emailTo = 'myname@domain.com';

// DON'T EDIT BELOW CODE
$subscriber_email = ($_POST['email']);

// Send email code
$subject = 'Hi!';
$message = "There's someone you need to contact!\n\nEmail: " . $subscriber_email;
$headers = "From: ".$subscriber_email." <" . $subscriber_email . ">" . "\r\n" . "Reply E-mail: " . $subscriber_email;

    if(mail($emailTo, $subject, $message, $headers)){
            header('Location: //domain.com/thanks.html');
            exit();
            }

} else {
echo "Error to send your request, please send an e-mail to: para myemail@domain.com";
// Exibe dados sobre o erro:
echo "Dados sobre o erro:" . mysql_error();
}
```

And finally, the conection.php

```
<?php

$n = -1;
/*
$n++;
$MySQL[$n]['dominios']  = array('127.0.0.1', 'localhost'); // PossÃ­veis dominios
$MySQL[$n]['servidor']  = '127.0.0.1'; // Servidor MySQL
$MySQL[$n]['usuario']   = 'root'; // UsuÃ¡rio MySQL
$MySQL[$n]['senha']     = ''; // Senha MySQL
$MySQL[$n]['banco']     = 'meu_banco'; // Banco de dados
$MySQL[$n]['persis']    = false; // ConexÃ£o persistente?
*/

$n++;
$MySQL[$n]['dominios']  = array('hijumbo.com');
$MySQL[$n]['servidor']  = 'localhost'; // Servidor MySQL
$MySQL[$n]['usuario']   = 'user'; // UsuÃ¡rio MySQL
$MySQL[$n]['senha']     = 'password'; // Senha MySQL
$MySQL[$n]['banco']     = 'databank'; // Banco de dados
$MySQL[$n]['persis']    = false; // ConexÃ£o persistente?


foreach ($MySQL as $key=>$servidor) {
    if (!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'])) {
        $usar = $key;
        break;
    } else {
        $encontrado = false;
        foreach ($servidor['dominios'] as $dominio) {
            if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], $dominio) !== false) {
              $usar = $key;
              $encontrado = true;
              break;
            }
        }
        if ($encontrado)
            break;
    }
}


$MySQL['conexao'] = ($MySQL[$usar]['persis']) ? 'mysql_pconnect' : 'mysql_connect';


$MySQL['link'] = $MySQL['conexao']($MySQL[$usar]['servidor'], $MySQL[$usar]['usuario'], $MySQL[$usar]['senha']) or die("NÃ£o foi possÃ­vel se conectar ao servidor MySQL no endereÃ§o [".$MySQL[$usar]['servidor']."]");


mysql_select_db($MySQL[$usar]['banco'], $MySQL['link']) or die("NÃ£o foi possÃ­vel conectar-se ao banco de dados [".$MySQL[$usar]['banco']."] no servidor [".$MySQL[$usar]['servidor']."]");
?>
```

Does anyone knows why I'm receiving the ***Access denied for user 'grondon'@'localhost' (using password: NO)*** ? Thanks

Comment: Did you add the user and did you flushes the privileges?

Comment: Please, [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). They are no longer maintained and are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). Learn about [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and consider using PDO, [it's not as hard as you think](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: Just to add an information: I use Godaddy services. So if there is something to do in the cpanel ...

Comment: Yes. I've already put all the privileges.

Comment: You're setting up the connection as 'root', not 'grondon'.

Comment: I think that's not the problem as this part of the code is under /** comments.

Comment: But I will learn more about PDO

Comment: This is unrelated to your question, but below where it says `DON'T EDIT BELOW CODE`, you really do need to edit the code. It's taking a value provided by the user (`$_POST['email']`) and inserting it straight into the header of an email. This is a **terrible** idea. Search for [email injection](http://google.com/search?q=email+injection) to find out why/

Comment: Is your connection file in another domain-machine??

Comment: `(using password: NO)` is probably signifying the issue.  No password is being passed.